# How to add text view and spinner view to Firebase Realtime Database on button click in android studio in a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

Hy, I am new to Android and Stack overflow.I am making an e commerce app and in the cart fragment when a user clicks the button I want to send the  products name, quantity, price, current time and current date to firebase database and send the user to checkout.I am trying to do it from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5k6leO4Lsg&t=555s) video but he is doing it from an activity and he is using Edit text. There is no error but when I test the app and I click the button the app shut's down. Please anybody help. I have searched it everywhere but I couldn't find an answer.

**CartFragment.java**

```
package com.example.shoppingcart.views;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;



import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.shoppingcart.R;
import com.example.shoppingcart.adapters.CartListAdapter;
import com.example.shoppingcart.cartholder;
import com.example.shoppingcart.databinding.FragmentCartBinding;
import com.example.shoppingcart.dataholder;
import com.example.shoppingcart.models.CartItem;
import com.example.shoppingcart.productholder;
import com.example.shoppingcart.viewmodels.ShopViewModel;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CartFragment extends Fragment implements CartListAdapter.CartInterface {

    private static final String TAG = "CartFragment";
    private ImageView productImage;
    private TextView productname;
    private TextView productprice;
    private TextView productcategory;
    private Spinner productquantity;
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    String randomUUID = uuid.toString().trim();
    ShopViewModel shopViewModel;
    FragmentCartBinding fragmentCartBinding;
    NavController navController;
    Button button;

    private void finishActivity() {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }

    public CartFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        fragmentCartBinding = FragmentCartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return fragmentCartBinding.getRoot();


    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        final CartListAdapter cartListAdapter = new CartListAdapter(this);
        fragmentCartBinding.cartRecyclerView.setAdapter(cartListAdapter);
        fragmentCartBinding.cartRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(requireContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        shopViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ShopViewModel.class);
        shopViewModel.getCart().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<CartItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<CartItem> cartItems) {
                cartListAdapter.submitList(cartItems);
                fragmentCartBinding.placeOrderButton.setEnabled(cartItems.size() > 0);
            }
        });

        shopViewModel.getTotalPrice().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Double>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Double aDouble) {
                fragmentCartBinding.orderTotalTextView.setText("Total: PKR " + aDouble.toString());


            }
        });

        button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.placeOrderButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CartFragment.this.getActivity(), CheckoutActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finishActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteItem(CartItem cartItem) {
        shopViewModel.removeItemFromCart(cartItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void changeQuantity(CartItem cartItem, int quantity) {
        shopViewModel.changeQuantity(cartItem, quantity);
    }



    }
```

**ShopViewModel.java**

```
package com.example.shoppingcart.viewmodels;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import com.example.shoppingcart.models.CartItem;
import com.example.shoppingcart.models.Product;
import com.example.shoppingcart.repositories.CartRepo;
import com.example.shoppingcart.repositories.ShopRepo;

import java.util.List;

public class ShopViewModel extends ViewModel {

    ShopRepo shopRepo = new ShopRepo();
    CartRepo cartRepo = new CartRepo();

    MutableLiveData<Product> mutableProduct = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<List<Product>> getProducts() {
        return shopRepo.getProducts();
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        mutableProduct.setValue(product);
    }

    public LiveData<Product> getProduct() {
        return mutableProduct;
    }

    public LiveData<List<CartItem>> getCart() {
        return cartRepo.getCart();
    }

    public boolean addItemToCart(Product product) {
        return cartRepo.addItemToCart(product);
    }

    public void removeItemFromCart(CartItem cartItem) {
        cartRepo.removeItemFromCart(cartItem);
    }

    public void changeQuantity(CartItem cartItem, int quantity) {
        cartRepo.changeQuantity(cartItem, quantity);
    }

    public LiveData<Double> getTotalPrice() {
        return cartRepo.getTotalPrice();
    }

    public void resetCart() {
        cartRepo.initCart();
    }


}
```

**CartRepo.java**

```
    package com.example.shoppingcart.repositories;
    
    import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData; import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
    
    import com.example.shoppingcart.models.CartItem; import com.example.shoppingcart.models.Product;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;
    
    public class CartRepo {
    
        private MutableLiveData<List<CartItem>> mutableCart = new MutableLiveData<>();
        private MutableLiveData<Double> mutableTotalPrice = new MutableLiveData<>();
    
        public LiveData<List<CartItem>> getCart() {
            if (mutableCart.getValue() == null) {
                initCart();
            }
            return mutableCart;
        }
    
        public void initCart() {
            mutableCart.setValue(new ArrayList<CartItem>());
            calculateCartTotal();
        }
    
        public boolean addItemToCart(Product product) {
            if (mutableCart.getValue() == null) {
                initCart();
            }
            List<CartItem> cartItemList = new ArrayList<>(mutableCart.getValue());
            for (CartItem cartItem: cartItemList) {
                if (cartItem.getProduct().getId().equals(product.getId())) {
                    if (cartItem.getQuantity() == 5) {
                        return false;
                    }
    
                    int index = cartItemList.indexOf(cartItem);
                    cartItem.setQuantity(cartItem.getQuantity() + 1);
                    cartItemList.set(index, cartItem);
    
                    mutableCart.setValue(cartItemList);
                    calculateCartTotal();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            CartItem cartItem = new CartItem(product, 1);
            cartItemList.add(cartItem);
            mutableCart.setValue(cartItemList);
            calculateCartTotal();
            return true;
        }
    
        public void removeItemFromCart(CartItem cartItem) {
            if (mutableCart.getValue() == null) {
                return;
            }
            List<CartItem> cartItemList = new ArrayList<>(mutableCart.getValue());
            cartItemList.remove(cartItem);
            mutableCart.setValue(cartItemList);
            calculateCartTotal();
        }
    
        public  void changeQuantity(CartItem cartItem, int quantity) {
            if (mutableCart.getValue() == null) return;
    
            List<CartItem> cartItemList = new ArrayList<>(mutableCart.getValue());
    
            CartItem updatedItem = new CartItem(cartItem.getProduct(), quantity);
            cartItemList.set(cartItemList.indexOf(cartItem), updatedItem);
    
            mutableCart.setValue(cartItemList);
            calculateCartTotal();
        }
    
        private void calculateCartTotal() {
            if (mutableCart.getValue() == null) return;
            double total = 0.0;
            List<CartItem> cartItemList = mutableCart.getValue();
            for (CartItem cartItem: cartItemList) {
                total += cartItem.getProduct().getPrice() * cartItem.getQuantity();
            }
            mutableTotalPrice.setValue(total);
        }
    
        public LiveData<Double> getTotalPrice() {
            if (mutableTotalPrice.getValue() == null) {
                mutableTotalPrice.setValue(0.0);
            }
            return mutableTotalPrice;
        }
    
    }
```

**fragment_cart.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".views.CartFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cartRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/cart_row"
            tools:itemCount="2"
            />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderTotalTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Total: PKR 26"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Proceed To Checkout"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please provide your error logs.

Comment: it is more helpful if we see logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you have to learn the first basically in android does not go started with MVVM arch so first work on basic funda ...

and work on the eCommerce model then go [ecommarceApp](https://github.com/axarlotwala/Shopping) It's a Bais E-commerce app with PHP it's only for your reference perspective.

your all problem can solve it its a basic model so refer it